# How to convert a 2-d array into a dictionary object

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of type string that looks like this:
`"test1|True,test2|False,test3|False,test4|True"`.
This is essentially a 2d array like so
[test1][True]
[test2][False]
[test3][False]
[test4][True].

I want to convert this into a `dictionary<string,bool>` using linq, something like:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> myResults = results.Split(",".ToCharArray).ToDictionary()
```

any ideas?

Comment: There is no such thing as an array of type string. I think you mean an array encoded in a string.

Comment: sorry, yes it is a string that I want to convert into a 2d array on the fly inside the linq statement and convert that into a dictionary object

Comment: The answers to this question just demonstrate how many different ways there are of doing things. Everyone's answer so far is slightly different, but all valid. My vote goes for [Marcelo's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817367/how-to-convert-a-2-d-array-into-a-dictionary-object/2817419#2817419), as I think it's the most elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First turn your string into a proper array:

```
String sData = "test1|True,test2|False,test3|False,test4|True";
String[] sDataArray = sData.Split(',');
```

Then you can process the `String[]` into a dictionary:

```
var sDict = sDataArray.ToDictionary(
        sKey => sKey.Split('|')[0], 
        sElement => bool.Parse(sElement.Split('|')[1])
    );
```

The [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) method takes 2 functions which extract the key and element data from the each source array element.

Here, I've extracted each half by splitting on the "|" and then used the first half as the key and the second I've parsed into a `bool` to use as the element.

Obviously this contains no error checking so could fail if the source string wasn't comma separated, or if each element wasn't pipe separated. So be careful with where your source string comes from. If it doesn't match this pattern exactly it's going to fail so you'll need to do some tests and validation.

[Marcelo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817367/how-to-convert-a-2-d-array-into-a-dictionary-object/2817419#2817419) answer is similar, but I think it's a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 8):

```
var d = results.Split(',')
               .Select(row => row.Split('|'))
               .ToDictionary(srow => srow[0], srow => bool.Parse(srow[1]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
var fullString = "Test,True|Test2,False";

var query = from item in fullString.Split('|')
            let splitted = item.Split(',')
            let value = bool.Parse(splitted[1])
            select new { Key = splitted[0], Value = value };

var dict = query.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
var resultsArray = results.Split(',');

var myResults = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

foreach (var str in resultsArray)
{
    var parts = str.Split('|');
    myResults.Add(parts[0], bool.Parse(parts[1]));
}
```